# Accessing id field of query returned object changes it to undefined

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, apollo

Im working on a react/mondgodb/graphql/apollo web application.  I have a query set up to get a member using a fbid (its a firebase Id that I insert as fbid in order to find a logged in member profile in my database by the firebase id).  When I do the query, I can console.log the query returned data as a whole.  If I try to access members of the data, I get that the object is undefined.  Here is the component where I query:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import { graphql, compose } from 'react-apollo';
import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase';
import { getMemberByFBidQuery } from '../../queries/queries';

import DataList from '../wishes/MyDataList';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    memberProfile: {},
    error: null
}

class DashboardGuts extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { ...INITIAL_STATE };
    }

    render() {
        const memberProfile = this.props.getMemberByFBidQuery.memberByFBid;
        console.log('memberProfile: ', memberProfile.id);

        return (
            <div className="dashboard container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col s12 m6">
                        <h4>My Data List</h4>
                        <DataList memberProfile={memberProfile} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const Dashboard = withFirebase(DashboardGuts)

export default compose(
    graphql(getMemberByFBidQuery, {
        name: "getMemberByFBidQuery",
        options: (props) => {
            return {
                variables: {
                    fbid: props.firebase.auth.O
                }
            }
        }
    }),
)(Dashboard)
```

When I console.log the memberProfile in the code above, I get all the data I expect returned from the query.  The console.log output looks like the following:

```
memberProfile:  
    {firstname: "jo", lastname: "blo", id: "1234", 
     fbid: "5678", __typename: "Member"}
     fbid: "5678"
     firstname: "jo"
     id: "1234"
     lastname: "smith"
     __typename: "Member"
     __proto__: Object
 }
```

The problem is when I try to access any of the fields within the memberProfile object - like id, I get errors.  For example if I change this line:

```
console.log('memberProfile: ', memberProfile);
```

To this:

```
console.log('memberProfile: ', memberProfile.id);
```

Then I get the error that I can't access id of undefined object.
[image]

Any ideas on how to access that id property?  In case it helps, here is the actual graphQL query:

```
const getMemberByFBidQuery = gql`
query($fbid: String){
    memberByFBid(fbid: $fbid) {
        firstname,
        lastname,
        id,
        fbid
    }
}
```

`

And here's the schema for that query:

```
memberByFBid: {
        type: MemberType,
        args: { fbid: { type: GraphQLString } },
        resolve(parent, args) {
            return Member.findOne({ fbid: args.fbid });
        }
    },
```

And here is the schema for MemberType:

```
const MemberType = new GraphQLObjectType({
name: "Member",
fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    firstname: { type: GraphQLString },
    lastname: { type: GraphQLString },
    email: { type: GraphQLString },
    fbid: { type: GraphQLString },
    wishes: {
        type: GraphQLList(WishType),
        resolve(parent, args) {
            return Wish.find({ memberId: parent.id })
        }
    },
    groups: {
        type: GraphQLList(MemberToGroupMapType),
        resolve(parent, args) {
            return MemberToGroupMap.find({ memberId: parent.id });
        }
    }
})
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Per TLadd's suggestions, I changed my render function but Im still getting error.  Her it is currently:

```
render() {
    console.log('look for loading: ', this.props);
    const { memberByFBid, loading, error } = this.props.getMemberByFBidQuery;

    if (loading) {
        return (<p>Loading...</p>);
    } else if (error) {
        return (<p>Error!</p>);
    }

    console.log('memberProfilexx: ', memberByFBid);

    return (
        <div className="dashboard container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col s12 m6">
                    <h4>My Wish List</h4>
                    <WishList memberProfile={memberByFBid} />
                </div>
                <div className="col s12 m5 offset-m1">
                    <div>Hello</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

But I still get the error if I try to console.log memberByFBid.id instead of just memberByFBid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hitting this error because you query has not loaded yet when your `DashboardGuts` component first attempts to render. From the [react-apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#graphql-query-data) on the data property (getMemberByFBidQuery in this case, since you specify a custom name config option in the graphql HOC):

> Make sure to always check data.loading and data.error in your components before rendering. Properties like data.todos which contain your app’s data may be undefined while your component is performing its initial fetch. Checking data.loading and data.error helps you avoid any issues with undefined data.

Following this advice, your render method becomes something like

```
render() {
  const { memberByFBid, loading, error } = this.props.getMemberByFBidQuery;

  if (loading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  } else if (error) {
    return <p>Error!</p>;
  }

  console.log('memberProfile: ', memberProfile.id);
  return (
    <div className="dashboard container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col s12 m6">
          <h4>My Data List</h4>
          <DataList memberProfile={memberProfile} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

You would likely want to handle loading/error state in a more appealing fashion, but the main idea is that you need to account for the data not being loaded yet in the render method, since it won't be in the initial render.

Comment: Added your suggestion - but still getting error.  Changed the render to your suggestion with the check for if loading or error.  Still get undefined error if I try to access memberByFBid.id bellow the ifs

Comment: I updated my post above to include changing my render function per your suggestions @TLadd

Comment: Ok - realized I can't console log it out in that component,  but I can grab it now in the component I am passing it down to.  So thats good!  Thanks!